# How to clip raster inside of circle (python gdal)

Tags: python, gdal, polygon, clip, masking

I have a source raster and an ERSI shape file, want to crop the raster into the circle.

[image: polygon on the raster]

```
raster = gdal.Open("raster.tif", gdal.GA_ReadOnly) #read raster
projection=raster.GetProjectionRef()
VectorDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile') #intialize vector
VectorDataset = VectorDriver.Open("boxes.shp", 1) 
layer = VectorDataset.GetLayer()
feature=layer[0] #select the first polygon (the circle shown in image)
geom = feature.GetGeometryRef() 
minX, maxX, minY, maxY = geom.GetEnvelope()
OutTile = gdal.Warp("cut", raster, format='GTiff', outputBounds=[minX, minY, maxX, maxY],xRes=0.05,yRes=0.05,dstSRS=projection)
```

But when I plot the OutTile, it shows only the corners of the polygon. I also tried the "cutline" argument, but then it croped the whole raster.

[image]

Comment: Now, you can try to subset the raster to each individual feature of the shapefile and then access them separately. This code can be perfectly used in this case, but it is a little bit more complicate. If you have some issues ask for advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you create a clipping layer with only the circular feature to use, your code can be simplified in this way (I use my own paths):

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

OutTile = gdal.Warp("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/cut.tif", 
                    "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/utah_demUTM12.tif", 
                    cutlineDSName='/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/boxes.shp',
                    cropToCutline=True,
                    dstNodata = 0)

OutTile = None
```

On the other hand, you don't need to explicitly read raster or get drivers, datasets or ogr features. You can use creation parameters of resulting raster inside gdal.Warp function.

In my case, involved layers look in Map View of QGIS as follow (but it is not necessary to load them for running script):

[image]

After running above script, resulting layer loaded in QGIS looks as expected:

[image]

**Editing Note:**

I added two more features to my original layer:

[image]

and after running same script, resulting layer loaded in QGIS is also looking as expected:

[image]

Comment: This way works, thanks. What if I have several features in my shape file?

Comment: It also works. Please, see my **Editing Note**.

Comment: Thanks, I got that. But I meant to subset the raster to each individual feature of the shape file, and then access them separately.

Comment: I know how to do that but your initial question was answered. You now need to loop all features for producing different clipped raster with above script, however, this is another question.

Comment: @xunilk as an addition to your comment, with `ogr.GetDriverByName("MEMORY")` each feature could be stored in memory, than you would **not** have to store each feature to the filesystem. at the end of each iteration, the feature would have to be deleted from the layer with something like that `layer.DeleteFeature(feature.GetFID())`